# how to set a specific position of image in hidden object game

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I am developing a hidden object game for android in eclipse. I have settle a background and want to put some small images on the background on specific positions using x and y axis. how to do it. i have searched a lot for it but haven't found anything helping.
i am giving my code. 
and yes i have used java prams with imagebutton method and set(x) and (y) method as well(which are only available in honeycomb 3.0).

here is the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_level1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/IbCross"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cross" />

</LinearLayout>
```

stage.java

```
package com.findmystuff;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Stage extends Activity{

    ImageButton ib1;;
    String st = "what the fuck is this!";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level1);

        ib1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IbCross);
        ib1.setX(445);
        ib1.setY(767);

    }
}
```

it is giving me error of "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 10): android.widget.ImageButton#setX"
and of course it want float numbers. if i set the min API to 11. then what would be the float notation of x and y axis.

is there any alternative to this function. which takes arguments of x and y axis and put that image on that specified position on the background? or something else. which is simple and not tedious as i have to put several images on different levels of the game.!!

thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Several possibilites. You can either use margins on your views, or set the translation... or override onLayout/onMeasure in a custom viewgroup. Beware of clipped children!

Comment: What I would suggest to you is that, if you are developing a game and you need some interaction with the screen as you said you need the image at x and y, and if you want to update in "real time" with user interaction, the you should create your own View class which will extend some view (depends on you) I would use surfaceview or relative. And in the onDraw callback method you can do what you what with the Canvas.

Comment: @cesztoszule.. so there's no default view i can use to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: @DemureDeviant Well you have to make your own which will extend some View, and it's really not that hard. Just need to know how to work with the canvas, and with callbacks. But if you really want to make a game for android, you can use libgdx. it's really fun to use it when you are familiar with it.

Comment: @cesztoszule..ok thanks..i am actually doing my final project..any suggestion for the future?..i want to be a developer of mobile games.